# Is there a way to have web driver add cookie to a browser?

Tags: webdriver

I want to add a cookie value to browser after deleting all cookies.Is there a way to have web driver add cookie to a browser ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, indeed.

Assuming you're using java, check out http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Cookie.html.

The constructor on the Cookie class is overloaded in such a manner to allow you to tailor the data to be added to your cookie.

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie(); //you'll need to add args since there is not a no-args constructor
```

Once instantiated, adding is easy:

```
driver.manage().addCookie(cookie);
```

I'll leave the finer details to you, but this should get you started.